# irreducible Polynomial in a Cipher

Tags: cryptanalysis

If we change the irreducible polynomial of the AES to someother irreducible or primitive polynomial, what effect will it have in security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial in the AES is $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ that is irreducible but not primitive. In fact, you can use an irreducible and primitive polynomial but you have to save 256 cases in computation. Another main reason for using $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ in AES is mix-column state. In mix-column state we need an MDS matrix. The best optimal MDS matrix is circular MDS matrix that is constructed with the third element of finite field ($1 \,,\, \alpha \,,\, \alpha +1$). If you want to use an  irreducible and primitive polynomial, you have to check that is there an optimal MDS matrix like  MDS matrix of AES. I think, AES is designed such that with minimum RAM can be applied and has a proved security. In other words, in min-max problem of cryptography (security and speed) AES is an optima algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can change the irreducible polynomial of AES to another irreducible polynomial. In doing so we have to implement a change of basis or change the polynomial for the S-Box, this may effect the security. Moreover research had been done on how to enhance the security of AES by changing the irreducible polynomial. See this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6422263) for detailed discussion.

Hope this helps.